undefined reference to `std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.30'
I'm writing a C++ code using grpc and opencv. I proceeded with the build with cmake and make. I specified the required library and the path of the .so file as well.
$ cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$MY_INSTALL_DIR ../..
$ make -j 4
The following error occurs when entering "make -j 4".
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so: 
  undefined reference to `std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.30'

Additionally, if I write a code that only uses opencv and proceed with compilation with g++, it runs well. I don't have a problem adding headers, but I get this error if I only write code like cv::Mat.
I've added this and that library to CMakeLists.txt, and I've added paths to environment variables.

That looks like a version mismatch or missing libstdc++. Are you really compiling and linking with g++ or are you using clang or linking with gcc?

The std::condition_variable::wait() method the library references should be provided by the C++ standard library (since C++11).  Even if opencv provides a C API, the fact that it has C++ dependencies means that you should probably link programs using it by use of a C++-oriented linker driver (such as g++ if you're using gcc).  If you use a C front-end or (unlikely) invoke the linker directly, then you will at least need to ensure that you include the C++ standard library in the link.
